# DIfference in execution time in MOV commands in 8051

Tags: performance, assembly, embedded, cpu-architecture, 8051

Why does the MOV bit,C command in 8051 takes more time than MOV C,bit command?

Comment: Interesting question. Additional data points, `CLR` and `SETB` are also 1 cycle. Furthermore `C` itself is just a bit in bit-addressable memory, so both instructions are actually just a bit-to-bit copy.

Comment: The answer will be in the instruction fetch, decode and execute logic, and is perhaps better asked elsewhere. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/.  But unless someone who might answer has access to the internal logic IP for the 8051 core, I doubt you'll get anything other than guesses.

Comment: @Clifford `PSW` **is** bit addressable (`D0`-`D7`).

Comment: @Jester : I stand corrected - it's been a long time since I used an 8051 (when they were still made by Intel!).  There is however no direct bit-to-bit copy,  you'd have to do bit-to-C then C-to-bit, so the operations are not (apparently) identical.  As I said the answer is in the logic and perhaps bus architecture design.

Comment: There is no bit-to-bit but that's effectively what both `bit,C` and `C,bit` do, so they seem to be the same to me. Yeah, guessing, but what could be a theoretical reason?

Comment: @Jester: Possibly writing `bit` takes a read-modify-write of the containing byte, but writing `C` doesn't because `C` is set up to be written efficiently (i.e. handled specially)?  Reading a bit from a containing byte is simpler.  I don't know 8051 at all, let alone anything about the internals, so this is purely based on your comments.

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah good point about writing C being cheaper, given that some instructions can do an operation and update C at the same time (e.g. `ADD`). A read-modify-write by itself also completes in 1 cycle though (`CLR` and `SETB`) it only takes 2 if the source is `C`.